# WebApi Handling exceptions in delegating handlers + ExceptionLoggers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, logging, exception, async-await

I've got a .NET WebApi project that adds two subclasses of `DelegatingHandler` in the pipeline - an outer handler that handles request/response logging, and an inner handler that handles various forms of authentication. We also have a global `ExceptionLogger` that logs exceptions (so a request that throws a `ValidationException` for example will have two log entries - the request+response, and the exception).

Our problem is that, very rarely, for certain requests, there is a delay of 5-30 seconds between the exception being caught in the `ExceptionLogger` and logged, and the exception being caught in the logging delegating handler. Our logging delegating handler looks like this...

```
try
{
    // an exception is thrown here...
    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    await LogRequestResponse(request, requestContent, response, stopwatch);
    return response;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // ...but isn't caught here until up to 30 seconds later
    var response = request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    await LogRequestResponse(request, requestContent, response, stopwatch);
    throw;
}
```

The authentication delegating handler is 'inner' to the logger, however it doesn't try to catch the exception or do anything else. There is also no activity in the database at this time, and no delays in publishing messages to our message queue.

The thing that is odd is that this only happens on two specific, unrelated routes - other requests and exceptions, even of the same type, being handled in the same way to do not have this issue.

Any pointers to possible causes or where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is another [delegate handler](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2016/12/08/fun-with-the-httpclient-pipeline/) processing this before either delegate handler gets a chance see the request/response?

Comment: The pipeline is `LoggingHandler` -> `AuthHandler` -> `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher` ... so no, nothing else that isn't part of the normal pipeline

Comment: How are you measuring that 30sec delay? If it's just off logging time stamps could it just be that your logging method is facing contention on a log file?

Comment: In Kibana we can see the exception log event created at one time, and the request+response event at a time x seconds later (not timestamp, the actual time the code ran), there's also a Stopwatch around the `base.SendAsync(...)` call that stops when the response content is recieved - so I am fairly sure the timings are correct